# Using viewmodels with recyclerviews

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview

This all very complex I hope I can explain it well. So, I'm using recyclerview to show a list of User Profiles in form of cards. Each card contains 2 buttons for different actions. Now these buttons require observing to a LiveData object inside a ViewModel (I'm using MVVM, Android architecture components and Kotlin extensions) when clicked. One button in particular needs to observe to different live data based on some condition. This is why I've created a function which takes the condition and returns suitable `OnClickListener`. I pass this to the recyclerview adapter.

Now the problem is I use the same RecyclerView in multiple fragments. Everything works fine when i use the recyclerview in the same fragment where the function is written. Everywhere else I get the error like following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{1ef5330} (b299012d-c9c2-427f-8387-a7888289701b)} not attached to an activity.
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:833)
        at 
com.halalrishtey.HomeFragment$$special$$inlined$activityViewModels$2.invoke(FragmentViewModelLazy.kt:80)
        at com.halalrishtey.HomeFragment$$special$$inlined$activityViewModels$2.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:52)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
        at com.halalrishtey.HomeFragment.getUserVM(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.halalrishtey.HomeFragment.access$getUserVM$p(HomeFragment.kt:25)
        at com.halalrishtey.HomeFragment$genInterestBtnListener$1.onClick(HomeFragment.kt:65)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:967)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

And the function which creates the OnClickListener looks something like this:

```
fun genInterestBtnListener(
        condition: Boolean,
        v: View
    ): View.OnClickListener {
        return View.OnClickListener {
            if (!condition) {
                userVM.initInterest().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { msg ->
                    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                    //More code here
                })
            } else {
                userVM.removeInterest().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { msg ->
                    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't observe to things inside the adapter, so whats the optimal solution for this without repeating code??

**Update:** I declare userVM like this:

```
private val userVM: UserViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

**Also** Here's my adapter code:

```
class CardDataRVAdapter(private var items: List<ProfileCardData>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CardDataRVAdapter.CardDataViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CardDataViewHolder {
        val inflatedView =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.profile_card, parent, false)
        return CardDataViewHolder(inflatedView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CardDataViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val card = items[position]
        holder.bindCard(card)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    class CardDataViewHolder constructor(
        v: View
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v), View.OnClickListener {
        private var view: View = v
        private var cardData: ProfileCardData? = null

        init {
            v.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            //TODO: Implement a proper onClickListener
            Toast.makeText(
                p0?.context,
                "${p0?.cardTitleTextView?.text} Card was clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }


        companion object {
            private val KEY = "CARD"
        }

        fun bindCard(card: ProfileCardData) {
            this.cardData = card

            if (card.isUserShortlisted) {
                view.showInterestBtn.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite)
            } else {
                view.showInterestBtn.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border)
            }

            if (card.data.photoUrl.length > 5) {
                Picasso.get().load(card.data.photoUrl)
                    .into(view.cardImageView)

                Picasso.get().load(card.data.photoUrl)
                    .into(view.cardAvatarImageView)
            }

            view.cardTitleTextView.text = card.data.displayName
            view.cardSubtitleTextView.text = "${card.data.age} - ${card.data.height}"

            view.showInterestBtn.setOnClickListener(card.showBtnInterestListener)
            view.sendMessageBtn.setOnClickListener(card.messageBtnListener)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question and show us how and where do you declare `userVM`? If you don't call `genInterestBtnListener()` do you still get IllegalStateException?

Comment: @harrytmthy If i remove the userVM function calls from my function then there is no error, see edited question

Comment: Could you add your Adapter to see how you set everything up ?

Comment: Added, check it out @Biscuit

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, every `LiveData` should be observed within the fragment/activity where instance of ViewModel class created.
I think the problem occurs because you trying to observe LiveData outside the fragment where its created.
You can observe LiveData outside fragment/activity with `observeForever`, but you'll also need to call `removeObserver` to avoid memory leaks

cmiiw

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is because you're using `view.` in your `bindCard()`function.

Is the showBtnInterestListener in your class? You might move it to your `Adapter` as it'll be more appropriate that the `Adapter` knows about Listener instead of the `data class`

Could you try to change your `Adapter` as such:

You declare the object you'll interact with in your class and then in the bind you call them.

```kotlin
class CardDataViewHolder constructor(
        v: View
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v), View.OnClickListener {
        private var view: View = v
        private var cardData: ProfileCardData? = null

        val showInterestBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.show_interest)
        val sendMessageBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.message_btn)
        val title = view.findViewById(R.id.card_title)
        val subtitle = view.findViewById(R.id.card_subtitle)

        companion object {
            private val KEY = "CARD"
        }

        fun bindCard(card: ProfileCardData) {
            this.cardData = card

            if (card.isUserShortlisted) {
                showInterestBtn.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite)
            } else {
                showInterestBtn.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border)
            }

            if (card.data.photoUrl.length > 5) {
                Picasso.get().load(card.data.photoUrl)
                    .into(view.cardImageView)

                Picasso.get().load(card.data.photoUrl)
                    .into(view.cardAvatarImageView)
            }

            title.text = card.data.displayName
            subtitle.text = "${card.data.age} - ${card.data.height}"

            showInterestBtn.setOnClickListener(card.showBtnInterestListener)
            sendMessageBtn.setOnClickListener(card.messageBtnListener)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It still crashes with the same error :( `showBtnInterestListener ` is actually a member of another fragment. Another problem is I observe a LiveData object inside `showBtnInterestListener ` so how can I put it inside the adapter. Please help :(

Comment: Yeah then the issue is not really the adapter, you should do [this course](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-recyclerview-fundamentals) about recyclerview and they'll tell you how to use listener, with `LiveData`